# Firebase Crash reporting for alpha & beta

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, firebase-crash-reporting, android-build-type

I'm finishing my first android app but I want to start with an Alpha & Beta test in the playstore. This is how I have my firebase setup

- 1 Firebase Project:

  - 4 Firebase Android apps:

    - 1 with package name com.myapp.appname.alpha
    - 1 with package name com.myapp.appname.beta
    - 1 with package name com.myapp.appname
    - 1 with package name com.myapp.appname.dev

I have done it this way so the release & dev crash reports are separated.
I thought, I do the same thing for alpha & beta. But apparently I can't upload an alpha & beta & release with different package names these are my buildtypes.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        versionNameSuffix '-DEV'
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
    }

    beta {
        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
        versionNameSuffix '-BETA'
    }

    alpha {
        applicationIdSuffix ".alpha"
        versionNameSuffix '-ALPHA'
    }
}
```

After I saw that this doesn't work I tried to change some thing to identify different builttypes like this. (this string packagename is just for information) (still no solution to my problem)

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        resValue 'string', 'packagename', 'com.myapp.appname'
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        resValue 'string', 'packagename', 'com.myapp.appname.dev'
        versionNameSuffix '-DEV'
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
    }

    beta {
        resValue 'string', 'packagename', 'com.myapp.appname.beta'
        versionNameSuffix '-BETA'
    }

    alpha {
        resValue 'string', 'packagename', 'com.myapp.appname.alpha'
        versionNameSuffix '-ALPHA'
    }
}
```

So my question is how can I receive the crash reports of the alpha & beta buildtype in another firebase Android app?

**My Solution ATM**

after the information @Doug Stevenson gave me. I figured a way how I can handle the alpha, beta, release and dev build.

1 Firebase Project for:

- 1 Android for Release, Beta, Alpha

1 Firebase Project for:

- Dev Android App

Now, I will still get all the crashes of the alpha, beta, release in 1 Report, because the playstore doesn't support multiple packagenames, and firebase does not support any other way of registering your app. So I have done 2 things to identify what on version the crash appeared.

**No 1:**
I gave each productflavor another version suffix. and an extra string app_version

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp.appname"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        resValue 'string', 'app_version', 'prod'
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        resValue 'string', 'app_version', 'dev'
        versionNameSuffix '-DEV'
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
    }

    beta {
        resValue 'string', 'app_version', 'beta'
        versionNameSuffix '-BETA'
    }

    alpha {
        resValue 'string', 'app_version', 'alpha'
        versionNameSuffix '-ALPHA'
    }
}
```

**No 2:**
I Added a applicationIdSuffix for the dev application (see above). This way I can create another firebase project with an unique packagename. so my dev data & prod data are separated.

**No 3:**
I wrote my on application to initialize a log when the application starts, so If something happens this is the last log I see in the firebase crash report logcat.

```
public class MidiMacro extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseCrash.log(String.format("%S      ----->      Android Version", getString(R.string.app_version)));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have multiple apps in a project, each of their crash reports and analytics will still be separate.  There is an app chooser next to the product title at the top of the page.  For example, if you select Crash Reporting on the left, the section that loads will have "Crash Reporting" at the top of the page with an app selector next to it.  However, your database, storage, and remote config are all shared between the apps.  This is detailed in my blog post about organizing your Android app builds.

Comment: Yes, I know but like I told you earlier I can't have multiple apps, because the Google Play Store does not support that. Is this a good practice to handle Alpha, Beta & Release as an alternative? Or would you suggest something else?

Comment: I was clarifying the way that Firebase gives you to separate your crash reports and analytics between different Firebase apps within the same project.  That is the only way.  Changing the version name of the app or any other resources don't change anything - that is just what the customer sees when they look for the app's version within the settings app.  There is no guarantee that a given log line will appear in a crash report, since log items may be pushed out of the queue due to memory constraints.  Even if it does appear, you'll have to manually go through all the crashes to find them.

Comment: Yes I know but there is realy no other way? because I cant have 3 applicationId's, (alpha,beta,release) because the playstore just simply does not accept that! If I would place them all in different projects, All the data is splitted ( database, storage, and remote config) so that is also not a solution.

Comment: There is filtering of crashes based on the integer version number of the app, and the version numbers for all the APKs in each channel of the play store must be unique and always increasing, so you can use that.  But that does not keep them fully separated.

Comment: No I know but I think that is my only solution because firebase does not support what I want to do. I gues, kind a strange that no one else wants to do the same thing as me.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase team has always recommended that the same app in different environments (dev, alpha, beta, prod, etc) is best accomplished by having a different project for each one.  That keeps them completely isolated from each other, so if you mess something up in dev, it doesn't affect your prod users.  Read [my blog post about this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html) for a complete discussion.

Comment: Oke yes, I get it for dev & release. But I don't get it for alpha & beta? these 2 need the same realtime database, OAuth,... So if I use multiple project for realase, alfpha & beta these won't have the same realtime database, OAuth,... if I'm correct

Comment: That's correct, different projects do not, by default, share any resources.  You can make an app reach into other projects' resources if necessary, but that requires extra coding.  If apps need to share the same default resources, they should be in the same project.

Comment: Yes oke so they need to be in the same project. But how can I do that because then they need to have different packagenames. In the playstore the release, beta & alpha all need to have the same package name. And that is not possible if you they are all in the same firebase project, am I right? So I think I need to use the method with extra coding because firebase does not support what I want to do? (is there a good tutorial for reaching into another project?

Comment: In the play store, all the channels for a single app (public, alpha, beta) require an APK with same application id, signed by the same certificate.  It won't let you upload an APK with a different id.

Comment: Yes I know so how can I do that with firebase?

Comment: Firebase doesn't care which channel you publish an APK into.  You'll need to manage the builds that go to your alpha and beta channels. Maybe branch your code or do something else to make it easier to split between the two.

Comment: Ok so how can I do that? Because I still need to use the database of my release build? I just don't get it how I can handle this correctly.

Comment: Set up another app in the store with a different package name if you need isolation between environments.  Invite your users to join the alpha/beta app and make sure you never promote its APKs to production so that everyone can see it.

Comment: No, that will just split your userbase, the playstore supports alpha & beta so why can't I just use that? I can't believe I'm the first person on earth that wants to do something like this

Comment: Because, like I said earlier, all the channels for a single app (public, alpha, beta) require an APK with same application id, signed by the same certificate.  You'll have to make a compromise based on the limitations of the systems you're using.

Comment: hmm, oke that is a shame. I will need to look for another sollution instead of firebase then

Comment: Oke @Doug Stevenson I edited my question with what I'm using at the moment. Do you think this is a good practice or would you do it another way?